# Pasar una variable Javascript a un archivo php como una variable distinta a php

Tags: php, javascript, firebase

[image: Aqui recibo el dato de realtime database de firebase, y se almacena mi dato cedula en, cedu]

¿como podría pasar esta variable a php, puesto que la necesito para hacer consultas sql a un servidor.

Resuelto

Envié a través de la fetch api, con POST la variable:

```
fetch('./php/views/certificacion_afiliacion_trabajador.php', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        body : JSON.stringify({'cedula': cedu}),
                    }).then(res => res.json())
                }).then(data => {
                    console.log(data);
                });
```

Php no me recibía el dato, con $_POST, asi que usé este comando para recibirla

```
print_r(json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")));
```

Muchas gracias por sus respuestas, me sirvieron para resolver mi duda

Comment: Podrías enviarla por POST mediante AJAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes enviar esa variable via ajax o utilizando axios, te doy un ejemplo:

tienes tu variable de js

`var cedula = snapshop.val().cedula;`

ya luego a partir de alli envias la peticion al servidor:

`axios.post(url, cedula).then( (res) => { console.log(res) }`

obtienes repuesta solo asi la recibirias en php y aplicas tu consulta.

Comment: Disculpa la ignorancia, como recibo esa variable desde el archivo de php :c, soy algo nuevo en el desarrollo.

Comment: Que versión de php estas usando? @MarteenMunevar

Comment: Generalmente se recibe asi `$variable = $_REQUEST['variable_que_viene'];`

Comment: Agradezco tu gran amable ayuda gustavo, uso php 7, cuando oprima el boton que tiene el evento de post de axios, lo debo redirigir con un window.location a mi archivo php y con request recibo la variable si?